# The same jquery version doesn't work if there is on Google Apis

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm very confused, so if I put this in functions.php, on Wordpress, it works

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://sitgesgroup.com/wp-content/themes/toolbox/assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js', false, '1.9.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

BUT,

if I put this it breaks

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.jsfunction modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Why if these are the same file?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean breaks to the things that need this jquery didn't work properly.

Comment: Not sure; do you explicitly add a dependency on jQuery for the other files that need it?  If not, perhaps the difference in latency between the two servers is having an effect?